# how to change bluetooth popup message language?

Tags: ios, iphone, localization, bluetooth

I want to show the bluetooth pairing korean message in my iPhone app.

I set General >> International >> Language >> korean in iPhone Settings.

But my app uses Bluetooth function. When pairing, pairing popup message is in English language.

How to change its popup message language?

Need to localize viewcontroller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to localize the strings in your app. Here is a great tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/localization-tutorial-for-ios

Comment: The Bluetooth pairing dialog is, for security, provided by the OS, not the application, so this doesn't address the specific issue.